# SQL Server Table Triggers update an aggregate table-update/insert multiple records

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2008-r2

(NOTE: My question is detailed and specific to our system so I will apologize for the length of the explanation before I get to my actual question in advance.)

We have a number of tables that need to have a portion of the data contained therein aggregated to another table.

I have tried, to the best of my ability, to ensure the trigger can handle multiple rows and not just single row transactions:

```
TRIGGER [dbo].[TR_SavedFiles_PlanLibraryMetrics] on [dbo].[SavedFiles]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (
        SELECT m.AccountID, m.PlanLibCode 
        FROM PlanLibraryMetrics AS m 
            JOIN PlanLibraryItems AS it 
                ON m.PlanLibCode = it.PlanLibCode
            JOIN inserted AS i 
                ON m.AccountID = i.AccountID 
                AND (it.ItemTypeID = i.CISFileID AND it.ItemType = 'FILE')
            JOIN Accounts AS a ON i.AccountID = a.AccountID
        WHERE a.Status = 0       
    )
    BEGIN
    UPDATE PlanLibraryMetrics 
    SET MetricValue = x.newValue
    FROM (SELECT COUNT(s.AccountID) AS newValue, it.PlanLibCode, i.AccountID
          FROM SavedFiles AS s
            JOIN PlanLibraryItems AS it 
                ON (s.CISFileID = it.ItemTypeID AND it.ItemType = 'FILE')
            JOIN inserted AS i
                ON s.AccountID = i.AccountID
                AND s.CISFileID = i.CISFileID
          Group By PlanLibCode, i.AccountID) AS x 
        JOIN PlanLibraryMetrics AS m 
            ON x.PlanLibCode = m.PlanLibCode 
            AND x.AccountID = m.AccountID
END
ELSE IF EXISTS (
    SELECT m.AccountID, m.PlanLibCode 
    FROM PlanLibraryMetrics AS m 
        JOIN PlanLibraryItems AS it 
            ON m.PlanLibCode = it.PlanLibCode
        JOIN deleted AS d
            ON m.AccountID = d.AccountID 
            AND (it.ItemTypeID = d.CISFileID AND it.ItemType = 'FILE')
        JOIN Accounts AS a ON d.AccountID = a.AccountID
    WHERE a.Status = 0
)
BEGIN
    UPDATE PlanLibraryMetrics 
    SET MetricValue = x.newValue
    FROM (SELECT COUNT(s.AccountID) AS newValue,it.PlanLibCode, d.AccountID
            FROM SavedFiles AS s
                RIGHT OUTER JOIN deleted AS d
                    ON s.AccountID = d.AccountID
                    AND s.CISFileID = d.CISFileID 
                JOIN PlanLibraryItems AS it 
                    ON (d.CISFileID = it.ItemTypeID AND it.ItemType = 'FILE')                   
            Group By PlanLibCode, d.AccountID) AS x 
        JOIN PlanLibraryMetrics AS m 
            ON x.PlanLibCode = m.PlanLibCode 
            AND x.AccountID = m.AccountID
END
ELSE IF NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT m.AccountID, m.PlanLibCode 
    FROM PlanLibraryMetrics AS m 
        JOIN PlanLibraryItems AS it ON m.PlanLibCode = it.PlanLibCode
        JOIN inserted AS i 
            ON m.AccountID = i.AccountID 
            AND (it.ItemTypeID = i.CISFileID AND it.ItemType = 'FILE')
        JOIN Accounts AS a ON i.AccountID = a.AccountID
    WHERE a.Status = 0 
)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO PlanLibraryMetrics
    SELECT i.AccountID, it.PlanLibCode, COUNT(s.AccountID)  
    FROM SavedFiles AS s 
        JOIN PlanLibraryItems AS it
            ON (s.CISFileID = it.ItemTypeID AND it.ItemType = 'FILE')
        JOIN inserted AS i
            ON s.AccountID = i.AccountID
            AND s.CISFileID = i.CISFileID
    Group By PlanLibCode, i.AccountID 
END             
END
```

And it appears to work, until we get to a system we have in place to "merge" accounts whereby all the records from the old account(s) have their accountid's changed to the primary account.

The behavior I am trying to accomplish is to update any existing records in the aggregate table and insert new records for anything that doesn't already exist for the primary account.

So my questions: does the existence of the If exists/elseif exists clauses actually make it so this trigger (and the rest of the triggers modeled on this one) does not actually handle multiple rows?  If so, I don't think my problem would be solved by writing 2 or 3 separate triggers for each table as I still have to check for an existing record every time (i.e. an update/delete trigger and a separate insert trigger)?  Should I move all of this to a stored procedure and pass in, for instance, a table variable that contains all the records from the inserted/deleted tables (something I thought of cruising around the forums)?

SQL is not my strong suit and triggers even less so.  Any help from the more experienced would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: Have you discounted the possibility of using indexed views to perform this aggregation instead? If you can use them, I'd suggest you do so - behind the scenes, they use something very like triggers but *that code has been used and tested* many more times than you could hope to.

Comment: I don't believe anyone has thought of a view.  I will take that idea to my supervisor for discussion.  Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, *storing* data that can be *calculated* is generally frowned upon (since you're *introducing* the opportunity for the computed data to be inconsistent with the base data). If you must do it, prefer to use built-in mechanisms rather than writing your own (since they're far less likely to be inconsistent or miss edge cases)

Comment: Should I post more here for clarity or create a new question to elaborate on this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer - no. The use of "if exists" does not prevent the correct handling of multi-row statements.

But let's be honest. If you struggle with tsql and triggers, then you should be writing separate triggers for each action **UNTIL** you have confidence in your approach and logic.

Your logic appears to be overly complicated, but no one knows your schema and how your tables are used. It also appears to be at least one error. In your insert section, you check for existence based on a.Status = 0. That same logic is not included in the associated insert statement. This has been propagated to the other 2 sets of logic.

For example, assume 5 rows inserted in SavedFiles. 1 matches a row in PlanLibraryMetrics, the others don't. What does your code do? After execution, only one row in PlanLibraryMetrics will be updated - you have skipped the logic needed to aggregate/insert the other 4 rows. Your deletion logic seems highly suspect with the right join; without knowing the actual and logic keys to the various tables it is difficult to understand.

And on that note - now is a good time to start commenting your code to help others (including yourself at a later date) understand what the code should be doing and perhaps why. And yes - please consider Damien's suggestion. A view, indexed or not, might be (probably is) a better approach - and certainly a safer, more easily maintained one.

Comment: Thank you.  I appreciate the feedback.  I will discuss the use of a view with the senior programmer... I don't think anyone has considered that before.